# Negative exponent at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.pow

Tags: java

How can i fix error Negative exponentat java.base/java.math.BigInteger.pow from my function:

```
static BigInteger eul(BigInteger n, BigInteger b) {

        BigInteger pattern = (n.add(BigInteger.ONE)).divide(new BigInteger("4"));
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(b.pow(pattern.intValue())));

        return result;
    }
```

error throw at line:

```
BigInteger result = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(b.pow(pattern.intValue())));
```

input
n=3214315236286878413828554688017932599492010774390476107169160882202257140006023
b=2424542564265464646464646412424987764446756457474245176752585282729789707797971262662662627967

output should be:
2012412197646109946818069059950164564377761312631574365459647649336933671988569

Comment: What line is throwing you an error ? The negative thing is making me think that your BigInteger is overflowing, but we need to know first the exact line.

Comment: @Lutzi edited post  ``BigInteger result = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(b.pow(pattern.intValue())));``

Comment: `pattern.intValue()` seems wrong to me. Are you sure your `pattern` is small enough to be represented as an int ? Plus, I don't understand why your using a String between your two BigInteger.

Comment: I guess becaouse of ``intValue`` - need to convert - BigInteger constructor should be String. Im really new with BigIntegers.

Comment: Take a quick look on the internet about `intValue()` and you'll see that "This method can also return the result with opposite sign". This method is only taking the 32 low-order bits of your integer, which means it could be negative depending on the highest bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `pattern.intValue()`

`pattern` is some enormous number. `.intValue()` converts that to an `int` (hence the name), which is why this goes wrong, as this doesn't fit (and happens to turn into a negative number due to how `intValue()` works when you call that on a bigInteger whose value exceeds what int can represent. The reason only ints go there is because if you put a huge number there, your RAM can't hold it and your CPU would take a few million years to calculate it. There'd be no point.

### How do I fix it?

By going back to whomever gave you this assignment. your code has a bug, but reading what it is intending to do, it is ((n+1)/4)^b.

Which is a number that has... *a lot* a lot of digits. Many, *many* more than what you expect for output.

Clearly that isn't what you really wanted, or if it is, no computer can calculate this, and the result would be nothing like what you wanted.

Possibly that output really is ((n+1)/4)^b, but mod something. Which the API does support: `b.modPow(pattern, FigureOutWhatTheModuloIsAndPutThatHere)`.

Comment: Oh man, that really mistake in my code - ofcourse i aimed for modulo. How its working. Thanks alot!!